# Button outputs infinite times

Tags: vb.net, generator

Alright so I posted a question here a few months ago and all the help got it all working except from one feature. I want it so that when the button is pressed it pastes a first name and last name and if you press the button again, it does it again. But at the minute, it only works once. Here's my code:

```
Public Class HorizonNameGenerator

Dim UsableChars() As String
Dim MyRandom As New Random
Dim FirstNameList() As String = {"Noah", "Liam", "Mason", "Zack", "James", "Jack", "Derick", "Owen", "Blain", "Borris", "Johnny", "Joe", "Joseph", "Terry", "William", "Rory", "John", "Jason", "Daryl", "Alex", "Josh", "Wu", "Gareth", "Carl", "Martin", "Marty", "Vincent", "Vince", "Vinny", "Bobby", "Bob", "Paris", "Jake", "Gage", "Jacob", "Ethan", "Simon", "Elijah", "Michael", "Daniel", "Thomas", "Tom", "Matthew", "Declan", "Logan", "Lucas", "Benjamain", "Aiden", "David", "Andrew", "Andy", "Sam", "Samuel", "Carter", "Henry", "Nathan", "Ed", "Eddy"}
Dim LastNameList() As String = {"Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Davis", "Miller", "Wilson", "Moore", "Taylor", "Anderson", "Thomas", "Jackson", "White", "Maris", "Martin", "Thompson", "Garcia", "Martinez", "Robinson", "Clark", "Rodriguez", "Lewis", "Lee", "Walker", "Hall", "Allen", "Young", "Hernandez", "King", "Wright", "Lopez", "Hill", "Scott", "Greens", "Adams", "Baker", "Gonzalez", "Nelson", "Carter", "Mitchell", "Perez", "Roberts", "Turner", "Phillips", "Campbell", "Parker", "Evans", "Edwards", "Collins", "Stewert"}
Dim FinalName() As String = {""}
Dim Number As Integer = 0
Dim FirstNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, FirstNameList.Count)
Dim LastNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, LastNameList.Count)
Dim FullName As String = FirstNameList(FirstNameIndex) & " " & LastNameList(LastNameIndex)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = FullName
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Dim UsableChars() As String
      Dim MyRandom As New Random
      Dim FirstNameList() As String = {"Noah", "Liam", "Mason", "Zack", "James", "Jack", "Derick", "Owen", "Blain", "Borris", "Johnny", "Joe", "Joseph", "Terry", "William", "Rory", "John", "Jason", "Daryl", "Alex", "Josh", "Wu", "Gareth", "Carl", "Martin", "Marty", "Vincent", "Vince", "Vinny", "Bobby", "Bob", "Paris", "Jake", "Gage", "Jacob", "Ethan", "Simon", "Elijah", "Michael", "Daniel", "Thomas", "Tom", "Matthew", "Declan", "Logan", "Lucas", "Benjamain", "Aiden", "David", "Andrew", "Andy", "Sam", "Samuel", "Carter", "Henry", "Nathan", "Ed", "Eddy"}
      Dim LastNameList() As String = {"Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Davis", "Miller", "Wilson", "Moore", "Taylor", "Anderson", "Thomas", "Jackson", "White", "Maris", "Martin", "Thompson", "Garcia", "Martinez", "Robinson", "Clark", "Rodriguez", "Lewis", "Lee", "Walker", "Hall", "Allen", "Young", "Hernandez", "King", "Wright", "Lopez", "Hill", "Scott", "Greens", "Adams", "Baker", "Gonzalez", "Nelson", "Carter", "Mitchell", "Perez", "Roberts", "Turner", "Phillips", "Campbell", "Parker", "Evans", "Edwards", "Collins", "Stewert"}
      Dim FinalName() As String = {""}
      Dim Number As Integer = 0
      Dim FirstNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, FirstNameList.Count)
      Dim LastNameIndex As Integer = MyRandom.Next(0, LastNameList.Count)
      Dim FullName As String = FirstNameList(FirstNameIndex) & " " & LastNameList(LastNameIndex)
     TextBox1.Text = FullName
End Sub
```

You need to put the code in the button click. The way you have it, it will only display the first name it generated at the beginning of the script because it doesn't repopulate with new values.